# A curve line with label connecting two tabular cells with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I want to make a **curved** line with a label connecting two cells as follows. In order to make the label stand out, the bounding box and border of the label must overwrite any objects below it.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\tc#1#2{{\color{#1}#2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|*{5}{>{$}c<{$}|}}\hline
n & A & A-10 & B & B-10\\\hline
1 & 5 & 5 & 7 & 9 \\\hline
2 & 10 & \tc{red}{10} & 14 & \tc{green}{18}\\\hline
3 & 15 & 15 & 21 & 27\\\hline
4 & \tc{red}{20} & 20 & \tc{green}{28} & 36\\\hline
5 & 25 & 25 & 35 & 45\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also use the `nicematrix` package that uses Ti*k*Z to draw the table and makes it thus quite easy to reference certain cells:

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}

\begin{document}
\[\begin{NiceArray}{ccccc}[hvlines]
n & A & A-10 & B & B-10 \\
1 & 5 & 5 & 7 & 9 \\
2 & 10 & \color{red} 10 & 14 & \color{green!75!black} 18 \\
3 & 15 & 15 & 21 & 27 \\
4 & \color{red} 20 & 20 & \color{green!75!black} 28 & 36 \\
5 & 25 & 25 & 35 & 45 \\
\CodeAfter
    \tikz{
        \draw[->, red] 
            (5-2.north east) 
                to[bend left] 
                node[circle, fill=white, inner sep=1pt, pos=0.5, font=\scriptsize] {10}
            (3-3.south west);
        \draw[->, green!75!black] 
            (5-4.north east) 
                to[bend left] 
                node[circle, fill=white, inner sep=1pt, pos=0.5, font=\scriptsize] {10}
            (3-5.south west);
    }
\end{NiceArray}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that it needs multiple compilations.

Comment: @TheRealMasochist As does the other accepted answer.

Comment: Do you notice a whitespace at the top when using `\documentclass[varwidth,12pt]{standalone}`? How to remove it?

Comment: @TheRealMasochist You are right, I am unsure why this is. I assume it is due to the construction of the `NiceArray`. I have to admit that I currently have not idea how to fix it properly.

Answer (score 12):

You can do that with `tikzmark` library.

I changed your macro `\tc`. Now it creates a node and takes three parameters (format, node name, content). Then I add a `tikzpicture[remember picture,overlay]` and there I draw the curved arrows between nodes.

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
%\def\tc#1#2{{\color{#1}#2}}
\newcommand\tc[3][]{\tikzmarknode[#1]{#2}{#3}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{longtable}{|*{5}{>{$}c<{$}|}}\hline
n & A & A-10 & B & B-10\\\hline
1 & 5 & 5 & 7 & 9 \\\hline
2 & 10 & \tc[red]{a}{10} & 14 & \tc[green]{b}{18}\\\hline
3 & 15 & 15 & 21 & 27\\\hline
4 & \tc[red]{c}{20} & 20 & \tc[green]{d}{28} & 36\\\hline
5 & 25 & 25 & 35 & 45\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[-latex,red]   (c) to[out=10,in=180]node[fill=white,inner sep=1pt]{\tiny10} (a);
\draw[-latex,green] (d) to[out=10,in=180]node[fill=white,inner sep=1pt]{\tiny10} (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]